# Setting up different options and getting their values

Tags: php, html, html-select

I'm using the following code to add various `select` elements to my page. However, as I'm doing this in a while loop, the value for all the elements is the same

```
function options($pos, $count) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $options = '';

        $STH = //code to get data from db

        $STH->execute();

        while($row2 = $STH->fetch()) {
            $options .="<option>" . $row2['name'] . "</option>";
        }

        $menu= "<select name='filter' id='filter'>
            " . $options . "
            </select>";

        echo $menu;
    }

}
```

I then need to get the value of each of the `select` element after the user presses a button. But as the name for each `select` element is the same I don't know how to do this. Is there any way around this problem?

For eg, If the count is 5, five separate drop down lists will be created (even though the options in each of them are identical). The user then selects the options relevant to him and presses the submit button. I then need to get the values that he chose from the dropdown menus but I can't figure out how to do this as the name for all the dropdown menus is the same

Comment: Can you provide expected output format...

Comment: What do you mean the output format? I'm basically echoing a bunch of select elements next to each other and need to get their values later on

Comment: this question is some kind of guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have many select tags with dynamic options

Solution is to make your name of select tag different(dynamic)

```
<form method="POST">
<?php
cust_options(5);
function cust_options($count) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $options = '';
        $j = 1;
        while($j < 4) {
            $options .="<option>" . 'option'.$j . "</option>";
            $j++;
        }
        $ind = $i+1;
        $temp = 'filter_'.$ind;
        $menu= "<select name='$temp'>
            " . $options . "
            </select>";

        echo $menu;
    }

}
?>
<input type="submit">
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

```
<select name='filter' id='filter'>
  <?php 
     while($row2 = $STH->fetch()) {
            $options .="<option>" . $row2['name'] . "</option>";
     } ?>
</select>";
```

Comment: The selects are setting up correctly. I need a way to get the value from each of them. I can't do this right now as they have the same name and id

Comment: @Ankush, sorry your point is not clear. Can you be more specific

Comment: If the count is 5, five separate drop down lists will be created (even though the options in each of them are identical). The user then selects the options relevant to him and presses the submit button. I then need to get the values that he chose from the dropdown menus but I can't figure out how to do this as the `name` for all the dropdown menus is the same